# Javascript keyevents for a game

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events, event-listener, keystroke

I am making a game where on clicking the spacebar the player moves from left to right. and again on clicking the spacebar the player will move from right to left. I have done the coding using keyevents but its not working.

```
game.prototype.start_handling = function()
{
var that = this;

$(document).on('keydown.game' , function(e)
{
    that.key_down(e);
    return false;
});

$(document).on('keyup.game' ,function(e)
{
    that.key_up(e);
    return false;
});
}
game.prototype.key_down = function(e)
{
var code = e.keyCode;
var f1 = true;
var f2 = false;
if(code == 32 && f1 == true)
{
    this.player.jump();
    this.player.do_move_right = true;
    f1 = false;
    f2 = true;
}
if(code == 32 && f2 == true)
 {
    this.player.jump();
    this.player.do_move_left = true;
    this.player.do_move_right = true;
    f1 = true;
    f2 = false;
 } 
}
game.prototype.key_up = function(e)
{
var code = e.keyCode;
var f1 = true;
var f2 = false;
if(code == 32 && f1 == true)
{
    this.player.jump();
    this.player.do_move_right = true;
    f1 = false;
    f2 = true;
}
if(code == 32 && f2 == true)
 {
    this.player.jump();
    this.player.do_move_left = true;
    this.player.do_move_right = true;
    f1 = true;
    f2 = false;
 } 
}
```

I have change it and applied... but still its not working. I want the player to move from left to right on clicking space and then stop and then again on clicking space the player will move back from right to left.

Comment: Where's your eventListener?

Comment: i have added event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for same condition twice ..

```
var code = e.keyCode;
if (code == 32) {
    if(!this.player.do_move_right) {
        this.player.jump();
        this.player.do_move_right = true;
    } else {
        this.player.jump();
        this.player.do_move_right = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i implemented this in my code but its still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Are you add a listener like this < body onkeyup = "myfunction()">

```
function myfunction(){
    var code = window.event.keyCode;
   // your code
}
```

Comment: $(document).on('keydown.game' , function(e)
 {
  that.key_down(e);
  return false;
 });
 
 $(document).on('keyup.game' ,function(e)
 {
  that.key_up(e);
  return false;
 }); i have done in this manner.